# Build failed: An error occured while downloading the source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, appharbor

Get this error after uploading to AppHarbor.

How can i investigate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an AppHarbor problem. We've recently updated this part of the platform and this problem should be solved.

Sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: We just added some tweaks, could you please try again?

Comment: it still happens. Can you recheck my specific build?